# What is the purpose of Solder Bridge?

Tags: pcb, stm32, schematics, soldering, layout

I am learning about STM32 controller now.

While learning I gone through the datasheet of ***STM32F429 display*** board in that board it has ***solder bridge***.

[image]

I don't know what is the purpose of that. Can anyone explain why it is needed and is that necessary to add in designing?

Comment: Do you mean the connector marked with red, or do you mean a solder bridge?

Comment: Just a short note: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ5xB.png) is also a solder bridge. They can be good or bad depending on context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your picture doesn't highlight a solder bridge, that's a connector CN3 with functions given in Table 7 of the [UM1670 Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00093903-discovery-kit-with-stm32f429zi-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (`sda`, `scl` etc).
[image]

---

A **solder bridge** is a simple kind of switch, made during soldering.  Instead of using an actual switch, or a configuration jumper, the two pads are joined with solder (or left open).  Normally these are for configurations which are very rarely changed, or are only changed when other hardware modifications are required.

Solder bridge SB1 is highlighted here, and has the effect of changing the connections of the reset button, with this description in the manual.
[image]

[image]

From ST [UM1670 Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00093903-discovery-kit-with-stm32f429zi-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

---

The phrase **solder bridge** also refers to a type of manufacturing defect, when solder joins two parts of a circuit.  This is also occasionally used to modify circuits intentionally.

[image]

Thanks @periblepsis

Comment: Yes! I go through it it actually a **RF connector**. Thanks jonathanjo! [PCB photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhXgV.png)